# What is Amazon S3 Staging Directory relevant for?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, tableau-api, amazon-athena

I am trying to understand what is the relevance of "S3 staging directory".

[Connect to your S3 data with the Amazon Athena connector in Tableau 10.3 | Tableau Software](https://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2017/5/connect-your-s3-data-amazon-athena-connector-tableau-103-71105)

It is a **mandatory** field in order to connect Tableau with Amazon Athena, but changing it *doesn't affect* the Catalogue and Database listing (which comes after successful Signin) at all as I tried multiple directories for the same set of Access Key ID and Secret Access Key.

Not just that, it allows to put any arbitrary directory path in there (add garbage path). Signin passes on solely based on valid credentials.

Answer (score 5):

The article you linked says that the **Amazon S3 Staging Directory** is called *Query Result Location* in AWS.

From [Working with Query Results, Output Files, and Query History - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying.html):

> Amazon Athena automatically stores query results and metadata information for each query that runs in a **query result location** that you can specify in Amazon S3. If necessary, you can access the files in this location to work with them. You can also download query result files directly from the Athena console.

Basically, Athena stores output in that Amazon S3 bucket. If it isn't specified, Athena can raise errors.

It is handy for retrieving query history, and can also be used to chain the result of one query as the input into another query.